# Compare todays data against end of month of the previous month DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Lets just say that I want to compare todays data (3/10/2021) against the data of the last day of the previous month (2/26/2021), I am using February 26 because is the last business day of the previous month, Is there a Way to do this?

Comment: How do you define last business day? or you have data from only business days?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the last day of February that is not a weekend (DAX doesn't have holidays, because each country can have its own free days).

```
calcForLastDayPrevMonth_noWeekend =
var __firstOfMonth = DATE( YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1)
var __lastDayPrevMonth = calculate( MAX(DateTable[Date]), FILTER(ALL(DateTable), DateTable[Date] < __firstOfMonth && WEEKDAY(DateTable[Date]) not in {1,7} ))
return
calculate( sum(Table[SomeVal]), Table[date] = __lastDayPrevMonth )
```